# Combine max and columns in a single query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables:

1. customer -> int ID, string NAME
2. purchase -> date DATE, int VALUE, int C_ID

In the table customer I have:

```
1, A
2, B
```

In the table purchase:

```
01-01-2019, 10, 1
02-01-2019, 20, 2
03-01-2019, 30, 2
```

I'd like to do a single query that will return the latest purchase for each Customer. So I'd like to get:

```
1, 01-01-2019
2, 03-01-2019
```

I've tried different select without success:

```
select max(purchase.date), customer.id 
from customer, purchase 
where purchase.c_id = customer.id
```

But the result is only:

```
2, 03-01-2019
```

So I cannot get the max per each line...

Is it possible? Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend *filtering* as opposed to *aggregation*:

```
select p.*
from purchases p
where p.date = (select max(p2.date) from purchases p2 where p2.c_id = p.c_id);
```

Comment: @MassimoSavazzi . . . As the OP, you can accept whichever answer you like.  But is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your query just needs a `GROUP BY` clause. Without it, all records are aggregated into a unique row, which contains the maximum date and a randomly picked customer id.

If you only need the customer id and date, there is no need to involve the customer table:

```
select c_id, max(date) from purchase group by c_id
```

If you need information that come from the customer table (like the customer name), then:

```
select max(p.date), c.id, c.name
from customer c
inner join purchase p on p.c_id = c.id 
group by c.id, c.name
```

Note:

- always use prefer explicit standard joins over old-school implicit joins
- using table aliases make the query shorter and easier to read